# Error: Cannot find module '.../webpack'

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm just starting with node, and server stuff in general. I was following along with a well-reviewed youtube video and am at a loss here. I installed webpack and webpack-dev-server both globally and in my project folder. Now if I try to run webpack (typing nodejs webpack in the terminal) or webpack-dev-server, it just give me this error:

```
andrew@AndrewLaptop:~/Documents/mean-todo-app$ nodejs webpack

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/andrew/Documents/mean-todo-app/webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Shoudln't it be looking in **mean-todo-app/node_modules/webpack** instead of **mean-todo-app/webpack**?

Again, new to all of this so I could be missing something stupid, but I did search to no avail.

Thanks

edit: guess I could have mentioned I'm on Ubuntu if that matters

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing " require("webpack");" inside node? (sans external quotes)

Answer (score 5):

try using

```
npm install webpack
```

and do this in the root directory of your app.

Answer (score 1):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
```

you can use './webpack' only if you have something.js in the same directory 
if you require modules installed from third party source like npm use only require('webpack');

Answer (score 1):

Directly use `webpack` on your terminal. You don't need to refer `nodejs` here. Refer this documentation for executing `webpack` via command line as well as `npm scripts`: http://survivejs.com/webpack/developing-with-webpack/getting-started/#adding-a-build-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. Struggled a few hours trying to figure this out. I'm on windows 10, so hopefully this will help you...

First, you need to run 2 separate processes. In Windows Power Shell, you run: node server

THEN... in another WPS, you run: webpack-dev-server

From Chrome, type in: localhost://8080

You don't want to run "node webpack-dev-server" in the second shell. That kept throwing me off.